# How to limit Google Pub/Sub delivery attempts by forwarding to a dead-letter topic?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to configure a Pub/Sub subscription with a dead-letter topic (cf. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics) in order to limit the number of times the message gets redelivered when it gets nack'd. To this end, I've created the following example program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

const (
    topicID           = "my-topic"
    deadLetterTopicID = "my-dead-letter-topic"
    subscriptionID    = "my-subscription"
)

var (
    pubsubEmulatorHost string
    projectID          string
)

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(&pubsubEmulatorHost, "pubsubEmulatorHost", "", "Pub/Sub emulator host (e.g. localhost:8085)")
    flag.StringVar(&projectID, "projectID", "my-project", "Google Project ID")
    flag.Parse()

    if pubsubEmulatorHost != "" {
        os.Setenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST", pubsubEmulatorHost)
        defer os.Unsetenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST")
    }

    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(context.Background(), projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewClient: %v", err)
    }

    topic, err := client.CreateTopic(context.Background(), topicID)
    if err != nil {
        if status.Code(err) == codes.AlreadyExists {
            topic = client.Topic(topicID)
            log.Printf("Topic %s already exists", topicID)
        } else {
            log.Fatalf("CreateTopic: %v", err)
        }
    }
    defer func() {
        topic.Stop()
        if err := topic.Delete(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Delete topic: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    deadLetterTopic, err := client.CreateTopic(context.Background(), deadLetterTopicID)
    if err != nil {
        if status.Code(err) == codes.AlreadyExists {
            deadLetterTopic = client.Topic(deadLetterTopicID)
            log.Printf("Topic %s already exists", deadLetterTopicID)
        } else {
            log.Fatalf("CreateTopic: %v", err)
        }
    }
    defer func() {
        deadLetterTopic.Stop()
        if err := deadLetterTopic.Delete(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Delete dead-letter topic: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    sub, err := client.CreateSubscription(context.Background(), subscriptionID, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{
        Topic: topic,
        DeadLetterPolicy: &pubsub.DeadLetterPolicy{
            DeadLetterTopic:     fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/topics/%s", projectID, deadLetterTopicID),
            MaxDeliveryAttempts: 5,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSubscription: %v", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := sub.Delete(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Delete subscription: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        sub.Receive(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
            log.Printf("Got message %q upon delivery attempt %d", msg.Data, msg.DeliveryAttempt)
            msg.Nack()
        })
    }()

    result := topic.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Hello, world!")})
    messageID, err := result.Get(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Get message ID of publish call: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Published message with ID %s", messageID)
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
}
```

The script runs in two modes, one with a genuine Pub/Sub project (called `my-project` here) and one using the [GCloud Pub/Sub emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) by setting the `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable. I would expect, given that the subscription's `DeadLetterPolicy` has `MaxDeliveryAttempts` set to 5, that the nack'd Pub/Sub message is delivered approximately 5 times (the docs indicate that this is a best effort). If I run the script on a real Pub/Sub project, however, I get the following output:

```
> go run main.go
2020/06/22 23:59:37 Published message with ID 1294186248588871
2020/06/22 23:59:38 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824637866440
2020/06/22 23:59:40 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824634417896
2020/06/22 23:59:41 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824634418592
2020/06/22 23:59:43 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824637866928
2020/06/22 23:59:44 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824638981864
2020/06/22 23:59:45 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824640667960
2020/06/22 23:59:47 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824634418712
2020/06/22 23:59:49 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824638982160
2020/06/22 23:59:50 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824640667760
2020/06/22 23:59:51 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824634418000
2020/06/22 23:59:52 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824633942168
2020/06/22 23:59:53 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824633942712
2020/06/22 23:59:53 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824640668296
2020/06/22 23:59:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824637448352
2020/06/22 23:59:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824633943336
2020/06/22 23:59:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824633943448
2020/06/22 23:59:56 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824633943560
2020/06/22 23:59:57 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824638259688
2020/06/22 23:59:57 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 824637448752
```

In other words, the nack'd message is delivered 19 times, nowhere near the 5 times I would expect. If I run the program using the Pub/Sub emulator, I get that the delivery attempt is always 0:

```
> go run main.go --pubsubEmulatorHost=localhost:8085
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Published message with ID 4
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:54 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:55 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
2020/06/23 00:00:56 Got message "Hello, world!" upon delivery attempt 0
...
```

Here the output is truncated for brevity, but the message is printed about ~200 times (10 times per second for 20 seconds), again far above the 5 times I would expect.

Is the `MaxDeliveryAttempts` field of the `DeadLetterPolicy` not supposed to limit the number of delivery attempts for nack'd messages? And why is the `DeliveryAttempt` field such a weird sequence of integers rather than one that simply increments by 1 each time (cf. https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub?tab=doc#Message)?

Comment: Generally this happens when you did not give the required permissions ( [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create) under ***Dead Letter Queue Options***) so PubSub can publish to your dead letter topic or subscribe to your subscription. Also, I must point that if writing to the dead letter queue topic fails, PubSub will continue to deliver the message to your subscriber.

Comment: you can use the following command to give the permissions: 
First: `PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT="service-${PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com" `

Then: `gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding <dead letter topic> \
 --member="serviceAccount:${PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"\
 --role='roles/pubsub.publisher'`

Lastly: `gcloud pubsub subscriptions add-iam-policy-binding <subscription with dead letter queue> \
 --member="serviceAccount:${PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"\
 --role='roles/pubsub.subscriber'`. Did it work for you?

Comment: As Alexandre mentioned, you need to provide the correct permissions to the Cloud Pub/Sub service account.

Additionally, the emulator currently does not support dead letter topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to further contribuite the community I am posting this answer from what I mentioned in the comment section.

The issue you described generally happens when you do not give the required permissions ([here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create) under Dead Letter Queue Options) so PubSub can publish to your dead letter topic or subscribe to your subscription. Also, I must point that if writing to the dead letter queue topic fails, PubSub will continue to deliver the message to your subscriber.

In order to give the necessary permissions, you can use the following commands in your shell environment:

```
PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT="service-${PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding <dead letter topic> \  --member="serviceAccount:${PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"\  --role='roles/pubsub.publisher'

gcloud pubsub subscriptions add-iam-policy-binding <subscription with dead letter queue> \  --member="serviceAccount:${PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"\  --role='roles/pubsub.subscriber'
```

Also, I would like to add @Mahesh Gattani coment, which mentions that the emulator currently does not support dead letter topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it through GCP UI.

```
Go to Subscription -> Click on Edit -> 
Go to Dead lettering -> 
Add max attempt(minimum number is 5) -> 
add the topic (where you want to send message once your maximum attempt exceeds)
```

[image]